# C# A* pathfinding for isometric tiles

Tags: c#

I am working on an Isometric game in XNA and am using a version of A* for pathfinding.

It works pretty well but I am having a problem with finding the best routes when moving diagonally. Rather than going diagonally (the shortest route) the path returned goes straight up and then across.

I have been reading online but cant quite figure out how to change it. I think I need to change the predicted distance so that rather than * 10, this would be * 14 for tiles directly above or below but this doesnt seem to work...

```
 public List<Point> Pathfind(Point start, Point end)
    {
        // nodes that have already been analyzed and have a path from the start to them
        var closedSet = new List<Point>();
        // nodes that have been identified as a neighbor of an analyzed node, but have
        // yet to be fully analyzed
        var openSet = new List<Point> { start };
        // a dictionary identifying the optimal origin point to each node. this is used
        // to back-track from the end to find the optimal path
        var cameFrom = new Dictionary<Point, Point>();
        // a dictionary indicating how far each analyzed node is from the start
        var currentDistance = new Dictionary<Point, int>();
        // a dictionary indicating how far it is expected to reach the end, if the path
        // travels through the specified node.
        var predictedDistance = new Dictionary<Point, float>();
        // initialize the start node as having a distance of 0, and an estmated distance
        // of y-distance + x-distance, which is the optimal path in a square grid that
        // doesn't allow for diagonal movement
        currentDistance.Add(start, 0);
        predictedDistance.Add(
        start,
        0 + +Math.Abs(start.X - end.X) + Math.Abs(start.Y - end.Y)
        );

        // if there are any unanalyzed nodes, process them
        while (openSet.Count > 0)
        {
            // get the node with the lowest estimated cost to finish
            var current = (from p in openSet orderby predictedDistance[p] ascending select p).First();
            // if it is the finish, return the path
            if (current.X == end.X && current.Y == end.Y)
            {
                // generate the found path
                return ReconstructPath(cameFrom, end);
            }
            // move current node from open to closed
            openSet.Remove(current);
            closedSet.Add(current);
            // process each valid node around the current node
            foreach (var neighbor in GetNeighborNodes(current))
            {
                var tempCurrentDistance = currentDistance[current] + 1;
                // if we already know a faster way to this neighbor, use that route and
                // ignore this one
                if (closedSet.Contains(neighbor) && tempCurrentDistance >= currentDistance[neighbor])
                {
                    continue;
                }
                // NOT PASSABLE
                if (Globals.mapArray[neighbor.X,neighbor.Y].Passable == false)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                // if we don't know a route to this neighbor, or if this is faster,
                // store this route
                if (!closedSet.Contains(neighbor)|| tempCurrentDistance < currentDistance[neighbor])
                {
                    if (cameFrom.Keys.Contains(neighbor))
                    {
                        cameFrom[neighbor] = current;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cameFrom.Add(neighbor, current);
                    }

                    currentDistance[neighbor] = tempCurrentDistance + 10;
                    predictedDistance[neighbor] = currentDistance[neighbor] + Math.Abs(neighbor.X - end.X) + Math.Abs(neighbor.Y - end.Y);
                    predictedDistance[neighbor] = predictedDistance[neighbor] * 10;

                    // if this is a new node, add it to processing
                    if (!openSet.Contains(neighbor))
                    {
                        openSet.Add(neighbor);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        // unable to figure out a path, abort.
        List<Point> noPath = new List<Point>();
        Point n = new Point();
        n.X = -1; n.Y = -1;
        noPath.Add(n);
        return noPath;
    }

private IEnumerable<Point> GetNeighborNodes(Point node)
    {
        var nodes = new List<Point>();
        if (node.X > 0 && node.Y > 0 && node.X < Globals.xSize - 1 && node.Y < Globals.ySize - 1)
        {
            // up
            nodes.Add(new Point(node.X, node.Y - 2));             
            // right
            nodes.Add(new Point(node.X + 1, node.Y));
            // down
            nodes.Add(new Point(node.X, node.Y + 2));
            // left
            nodes.Add(new Point(node.X - 1, node.Y));

            // DIAGONAL
            if (node.Y % 2 == 0)
            {
                // UP LEFT
                nodes.Add(new Point(node.X, node.Y - 1));                
                // UP RIGHT
                nodes.Add(new Point(node.X - 1, node.Y - 1));
                // DOWN LEFT
                nodes.Add(new Point(node.X-1, node.Y + 1));
                // DOWN RIGHT
                nodes.Add(new Point(node.X, node.Y + 1));
            }
            else
            {
                // UP LEFT
                nodes.Add(new Point(node.X+1, node.Y - 1));
                // UP RIGHT
                nodes.Add(new Point(node.X, node.Y - 1));
                // DOWN LEFT
                nodes.Add(new Point(node.X, node.Y + 1));
                // DOWN RIGHT
                nodes.Add(new Point(node.X+1, node.Y + 1)); 
            }
        }

        return nodes;
    }
```

Comment: If I remember right when I played around with A* on 2d tiles, you have to make the cost of traversal to them cheaper than the adjacent tiles so the cost is lower. It looks like you are going off of actual pixel distances, but you want to assign arbitrary values you can tweak for manipulate the cost.

Comment: I'm not sure how you're getting neighbors. Wouldn't up be `X, Y-1`, down be `X, Y+1`, up-left be `X-1, Y-1`, etc? Additionally, your question says that you expect the character to "[go] diagonally", but your code comment says "a square grid that doesn't allow for diagonal movement." Can you upload a picture of what you're expecting and what you're seeing?

Comment: Apologies, the comments are old, ive used the same code for a number of various games previously. The tiles are layed out isometricly so going directly upwards will always be x, y-2